# Join a table without creating a foreign key or add objects that break foreign key relationship?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am building a project where I have two SQL tables: `wikispy_edit` and `wikispy_rdns`. `wikispy_edit` contains - among other things - an `ip` column with an index, which is the same data type as `ip` column in `wikispy.rdns`, which is a primary key there. The problem is that I cannot connect these two with `django.db.models.ForeignKey`, because some of the `wikispy_edit` `ip` values do not have a corresponding value in `wikispy_rdns`. While Django doesn't seem to complain during `./manage.py migrate`, it doesn't allow me to insert such objects using its ORM, which is annoying.

Is there a way I could model this relationship and still achieve the effect of `Edit.objects.select_related().filter(rdns__rdns__somequery="blah")`? I need a similar syntax because this is the only I found that allows me to perform this query in a single SQL statement and this sometimes pulls thousands of objects. If possible, I would prefer to avoid raw SQL queries.

Here's what I used so far:

```
class Edit(models.Model):                                                          
    wikipedia_id = models.IntegerField()                                           
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024)                                      
    wiki = models.ForeignKey('Wiki')                                               
    rdns = models.ForeignKey('RDNS', db_column='ip')                              


class RDNS(models.Model):                                                          
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(primary_key=True)                            
    rdns = models.CharField(max_length=253)
```

This worked well, but the problem is that this way I cannot insert a new `Edit` that has an IP not mentioned in `wikispy_rdns`. How could I work around either the edition or querying problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `blank=True, null=True` to the declaration of `Edit.rdns`

Comment: How can I set the `ip` column then? So far, I only tried `e.rdns = RDNS.objects.get(ip=something)` but this obviously won't work when the IP is not in `wikispy_rdns`.

Comment: It cannot, because I can't find an object for IP that doesn't exist in `wikispy_rdns` and set it. And I don't really need to - I'd just like to set IP column.